# Unable to scroll after more than one time on touch devices(tablets)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have a web mapping application where we have forms showing up for various functionalities. The scrollbar in the form works fine for desktop applications. But in tablets it works weirdly.

The first time when the application is loaded and a form (jquery dialog) is opened the scroll bar works fine. But the second time onward it fails to run. Below is the webkit scrollbar css we are using. What could be the reason for such behavior?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /* background:#dfdfdf;
    border: thin solid lightgray;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #dfdfdf inset; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #6b6b6b;
    border: thin solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

Comment: This css is probably not your source of error, since it doesn't change with user clicks. Can you share a little more of your code?

Comment: Do you have these properties applied to the element that requires scroll? overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: @Valius79 I did try using overflow-scrolling but it didnt help either.

Comment: Can you share more of your code like @rafaelcastocouto suggested?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto unfortunately I cannot in this case.